# How to filter data from Firebase Firestore the right way?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I'm retrieving data from my firestore that I'm putting in a FLatList that displays job ads, and I want the user to be able to filter the ads according to their liking.

The thing is that the user might filter some of the tags, and leave other tags like they are, so the query that will be sent to Firsbase will be conditional. I'm using the `where()` function as suggested in the documentation, but I'm getting an error saying "TypeError: null is not an object"

Here's my code:

```js
  const filterData = () => {
    setNoAds(false);
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "posts"),
      city && where("city", "==", city),
      jobType && where("jobType", "==", jobType),
      jobTime && where("jobTime", "==", jobTime),
      sex && where("sex", "==", sex),
      orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
    );

    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setPosts(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
      if (querySnapshot.size < 1) {
        setNoAds(true);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an array of conditions:

```
let conditions = [];
if (city) conditions.push(where("city", "==", city));
if (jobType) conditions.push(where("jobType", "==", jobType));
if (jobTime) conditions.push(where("jobTime", "==", jobTime));
if (sex) conditions.push(where("sex", "==", sex));
```

And then pass that to the query:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "posts"),
  conditions,
  orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
);
```

I think the `query` function accepts an array of conditions, but if not - you can destructure it with:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "posts"),
  ...conditions,
  orderBy("timeStamp", "desc")
);
```